# Background image on its full size but 2nd half of a screen is still empty

Tags: html, css, vue.js, background-image

I have a problem with my vue.js application, when I inspect the element it tells me that background image is on its max weight and max height, but here is what it looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G9NN.png)

Here is my html:

```
 <div class="hero-image">
<div>
<h1 class="text-center mb-5" >Prijava</h1>
</div>
 <form @submit.prevent="signin">
   <div class="kontejner">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label style="margin-left:1.3%" class="forma" for="korisnicko_ime">Korisnicko ime</label> <br>
      <input v-model="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="emailField" aria-describedby="emailHelp"  > 
    </div> <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label style="margin-left:-4%" class="forma" for="passwordField">Lozinka</label> <br>
      <input v-model="password" type="lozinka" class="form-control" id="passwordField" >
    </div> <br>
   </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn mt-5">Prijava</button> </form> 
       <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text-text-muted">Niste registrirani?</small>
 </div>
```

Here is app.vue html code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is my css code, but I tried everything including with changing my width and height and still nothing, it is still recognized as full screen but it is cut in half anyways...

```
.hero-image {
background-image: url("/assets/zrnca2.jpg");
background-position: center bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

I'd be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Hello there, not sure in what way it is "cut in half". Is it vertically, so the image should be higher? 

Try adding a padding in .hero-image. Like padding: 10vh 0; 
Using 100% 100% on background-size is weird. :) 
Use cover instead.

Comment: Yeah, using 100% 100% is a bad practice but I was trying everything, I tried putting min-height on 100%, but it seems it's not on css.. because when I inspect an element on my site it can't reach that other half.. so I think it's something wrong with vue application.

Comment: A mere line of CSS is hardly ever enough to properly describe such problems. You need to give us a proper [mre] that actually illustrates the issue.

Comment: Okay, I edited my problem, and added more code. Apologies if I was vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS3 have the have the values 'cover' or 'contain' of the property background-size, which can be the solution in your case.

'cover': Makes the background image cover the entire container, but will stretch or cut off the image if the image size doesn't match the container size.

'contain': Will make the background image fully visible

Like this:

```
background-size: cover;
```

or:

```
background-size: contain;
```

or both:

```
background-size: contain, cover;
```

It's difficult to say what will work best for you because I haven't seen your code in context, but I think 'contain' or a combination 'contain, cover' will be the best solution in your case.

Read more about 'contain' and 'cover' here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Thanks, but it seems it's the problem in app.vue, I tried everything with my css  but it isn't fixed yet. (cover and min-height doesn't help)

Comment: If you suspect that Vue.js is the problem, try removing the Vue app from the code and check that the background image is displayed correctly before you're inject the Vue.js app.

Comment: This might seems trivial, and it's difficult to see from the code you have posted. Double check that <div class = "hero-image"> encloses all the content where you want to have the background image, and that every </div> is in the right place. It's easy to make mistakes like this in HTML. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'cover':

```css
html { 
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/200/300") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
</html>
```